# How to create a link between GNS3 and a VMWare Workstation VM that is totally isolated from the physical host?

Tags: networking, dhcp, vmware-workstation, cisco-catalyst, gns3

My physical host machine runs `windows server 2012 R2` with a `DHCP server`.
I have the following topology in `GNS3`:
[image]

- Windows Server is the **physical machine**, it is connected to **both VMNet 2 and VMNet 3** networks.
- Windows 7 is a Virtual Machine running Windows 7 with a NIC plugged in **VMNet 3**.
- R1 is a Layer 3 cisco switch: f1/0 is assigned to vlan 9 and f1/15 is assigned to vlan 10

The problem is whenever **the Windows 7 machine issues a DHCP discover** it gets broadcasted in both VMNET 2 and VMNET 3, the purpose of the manipulation that I am making is **to demonstrate the L3 switch capability to forward DHCP discover packets** even if the DHCP server is not in the same broadcast domain with the DHCP client(ip helper-address command).

I need a way to link R1 with the Windows 7 machine **directly**.
I have tried two things so far:

- Removing VMNET 3 from the physical host makes GN3 unable to recognize it.
- Setting a bogus IP address for the VMNET 3 interface for the physical machine didn't work and caused generation of looping packets.

Should I consider using L2 filtering mecanisms or Is there a way to create a virtual broadcast domain between R1 in GNS3 and the Windows 7 VM?